# Add to cart button not displaying inside custom text in drupal 8 views

Tags: views, commerce

I created a  product display view in drupal8 to display the product.
For this, I added some fields like product price, title, and `" add to cart"` form.
When I call all the fields inside custom text fields, the add to cart button is not displaying on the page.  To display the `" add to cart"` button, I am using

> {{ variations_target_id }}

from replacement patterns.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can't rewrite the output of rendered entities (add to cart form) with replacement patterns for in D8 views.

I ran into this same problem and discussed it with the maintainer of the commerce_variation_cart_form module. You can read about it here: https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_variation_cart_form/issues/3081903

Specifically this from comment #17 https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_variation_cart_form/issues/3081903#comment-13269416

> All the render code runs including the form generation and extra field addition, but anything in a views field rewrite is then run through Xss::filterAdmin() to remove dangerous tags, and apparently form is a dangerous tag